# Displaying and hiding div after returning from ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

On my page I have a several calls to my server using jquery. I would like to show a result div where information about success/failure will be displayed, e.g. green div with success information and red div with failure information. This div should be seen for 1-2 seconds and disappear automatically. I created a viewModel for this purpose:

```
public class ResultMessageViewModel
{
  public ResultMessageKind KindOfMessage {get;set;}
  public string Content {get;set;}
}
```

On my controllers action I return the PartialView as follows:

```
return PartialView("ResultMessagePartial", new ResultMessageViewModel() { KindOfMessage= ResultMessageKind.Success", Content="Operation finished successfully"});
```

My ajax calls are something like that:

```
$(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#AnswerTheQuestion", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var answerContent = $("#AnswerContent").val();
                var messageId = $(this).parent().children("#rootMessageId:first").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.href,
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { rootMessageId: messageId, content: answerContent },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        //show success result div
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        //show failure result div
                    }
                });
            });
```

My question is: how can I achieve a functionality where my result div will be automatically displayed for a specific amount of time (like 1-2 seconds) either in success/error handlers? This will be some kind of notification for a user whether process finished successfully or not.  I would like to achieve such functionality with DRY principle preserved as much as it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout()` to execute a function after a specified amount of time.

Example: `setTimeout(function, delay);`

You'll call the method and pass the result/output and the desired time interval.

```
success: function (result) {
    // show message for 2 seconds
    show_message(result, 2)
}
```

The method used to show/hide the error could be something like this:

```
var show_message = function(message, interval){
    $('.message-div')
        .text(message)
        .css('display', 'block')
        .animate({
            opacity:1
        }, 200);
    setTimeout(
        $(function(){
            $('.message-div')
                .animate({
                    opacity:0
                }, 200, function(){
                    $(this).css('display','none');
                 });
        }), interval * 1000
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var hideSuccess = function(){ $('#success').hide() });
    var hideFailure = function(){ $('#failure').hide() });

    $(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "#AnswerTheQuestion", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var answerContent = $("#AnswerContent").val();
            var messageId = $(this).parent().children("#rootMessageId:first").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                data: { rootMessageId: messageId, content: answerContent },
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    //show success result div
                    $('#success').show()
                    setTimeout(hideSuccess,3000);
                },
                error: function () {
                    //show failure result div
                    $('#failure').show()
                    setTimeout(hideFailure,3000);
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
success: function(result){
    ('#successmsg').css('visibility', 'visible');
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#successmsg').hide();",3000 );
}
```

Similarly for error:

```
error: function{
    ('#errormsg').css('visibility', 'visible');
    setTimeout( "jQuery('#errormsg').hide();",3000 );
}
```

Assuming that the success or error message is in a `div` with `id="successmsg"` and `id="errormsg"`and they are set to `visibility:hidden` by CSS, this will set `visibility:visible`, and after 3 seconds hide it again.